# Highcharts - Custom Maps

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts, maps

We have a .NET MVC web application where we are using Custom maps (we don’t have license for this) from High charts on one of the screen to display only British Isles on the maps by plotting Latitude and Longitude points. It is working well in the local machine (refer second screenshot). However after deploying the application we are not able to sign in to the app and it continuously gives an error and pop up that says “We couldn’t sign you in” (refer first screenshot for reference).
We tried to remove the maps from the application and deployed again and then it is working fine. This is being the blocker for us from more than a week and we are unable to proceed and deploy our recent changes.[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O34pE.png)
Could someone please advise if this is happening because we are not using licensed highcharts maps or is this some other issue and what could be that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @dev. Please show a simplified version of your case at the online code editor.  Rather it won't be a problem with the license.